# Scanning for files that contain variable name

Tags: java, tesseract, scanning

I have a simple piece of code that currently uses tesseract OCR to read the text in any given image and then count how many lines it produces. However, I would like to search a directory for any document containing a string (such as M000123456) and return a number of how many documents contain that in their name and compare that to the number tesseract output. The documents are named liked so: M000123456_V987654_05-07-2000.pdf. What's the best way to do this?

```
import java.io.File;

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TesseractException {
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();

        tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\mmx0409\\Downloads\\Tess4J-3.4.8-src\\Tess4J\\tessdata");

        // the path of your tess data folder
        // inside the extracted file
        String text
                = tesseract.doOCR(new File("C:\\Users\\mmx0409\\Downloads\\testimage.png"));

        // path of your image file
        System.out.print(text);
        System.out.println(text.lines().count()); // count the number of lines tesseract saw

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare that to the number tesseract output"?

Comment: There should be multiple documents with the string in their name and the number of documents should be equal to the number that tesseract output.

Comment: Check the answer. You need to pass directory-path where your files are and search-string which in your case "M000123456"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to count the number of the document which is having searchString in its name.

```
public int countDocuments(String directoryPath, String searchString) {
    File folder = new File(directoryPath);

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            if (fileName.contains(searchString)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```